# Updating current XML file through C#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble manipulating my code to update an existing xml file with more data. My code is as below and I used an if statement, but I get an error which causes the programme to crash. Can somebody please help me as to where I am going wrong...

Code samples

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("order.xml"); //Loads the xml file.

        XElement xml = new XElement("MenuInfo",
            new XElement("Meal",
            new XElement("Data1", mealListView.SelectedValue.ToString()),
            new XElement("Data2", _seat),
            new XElement("Data3", buttonTable1.Text)
            )
            );
        if (xmlDoc == null)
        {
            xml.Save("order.xml");
        }
        else
        {
            xmlDoc.Add(xml);
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What are you expecting?  What line is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `XElement` to the `Root` of the xmlDoc. You can't add element directly in the document, you should add it in the root node. You can't have 2 root nodes in xml.

```
 xmlDoc.Root.Add(xml);
```

Also the part of your code where you are checking for null doesn't have any meaning. Do this.

```
    if (xmlDoc == null)
    {
        //show some exception or error message and leave the method.
    }
```